# Fetch Api data is displaying undefined in html webpage but working in console

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch-api, simple-html-dom

```
function getdata() {
  fetch(
    "https://api.lrs.org/random-date-generator?year=2015&source=api-docs"
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => data)
    .then(function (data) {
      let htmldata = "";
      htmldata = `<tr>
            <th>Quarter</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Date of Birth-</th>
            <th>Longest Day</th>
            <th>Unix</th>
            </tr>`;
           

let ndata = JSON.stringify(data);
      for (r in ndata) {
        
        htmldata += `<tr>
            <td>${r.quarter}-</td>
            <td>${r.day}-</td>
            <td>${r.month}-</td>
            <td>${r.db}-</td>
            <td>${r.long}-</td>
            <td>${r.unix}</td>
            </tr>`;
      
      }
      
      document.getElementById("rdata").innerHTML = htmldata;
    });
}

getdata();
```

data is displaying in the console but not stored in htmldata variable nor displaying in a webpage(showing undefined).
Api data is showing in Objects in console not working in any html page. and data is looping but values doesn't get stored, maybe?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` turns your data back into a JSON string, which is probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API returns an object with two properties, `messages` and `data`. You only need the `data` property.

After that, loop through the values of the `data` property with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), which turns the object into an iterable object that exposes the values of the properties that you can loop over.

```
function getdata() {
  fetch("https://api.lrs.org/random-date-generator?year=2015&source=api-docs")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(({ data }) => data) // Return the data property
  .then(function (data) {
    let htmldata = `<tr>
      <th>Quarter</th>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Date of Birth-</th>
      <th>Longest Day</th>
      <th>Unix</th>
      </tr>
    `;

    for (const entry of Object.values(data)) {
      htmldata += `<tr>
        <td>${entry.quarter}-</td>
        <td>${entry.day}-</td>
        <td>${entry.month}-</td>
        <td>${entry.db}-</td>
        <td>${entry.long}-</td>
        <td>${entry.unix}</td>
        </tr>
      `;
    }
      
    document.getElementById("rdata").innerHTML = htmldata;
  });
}

getdata();
```